# org.hibernate.exception.constraintviolationexception in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am an beginner in java.
I am trying to insert into a table 'employee' which has a foreign key 'org_id' in table 'organisation'.I am getting a constraint violation exception since my code is trying to insert null into foreign key.Below is my code.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "organisation/landing",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

Let me if how to correctly do it.

Comment: Don't try to insert null into foreign key.

Comment: Do you have any code reference. It might be helpful to me.Thanks In advance

Comment: You can't save an `Employee` without an `Organization` since you've defined your entity model in a way that every employee must belong to an organization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first load Organization entity from DB

```
Organization organization = organizationRepository.findOne( /* org_id */ );
```

Then set it to employee

```
employee.setOrganization(organization);
```

and only then save employee

```
employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

BTW, passing persistent entities as request body is bad practice, as well as manipulating persistent entities at Controller level